# Allowing only certain roles to see certain content within a view

Tags: 7, views, users

I am trying to make a martial arts site, where there is a feature allowing a member to log in, and view the techniques of his specific belt. If he is a black belt, he can view all of the techniques, but people of a lower belt can only view techniques of their belt or lower. I am trying to do this by using roles, and viewing permissions of those specific roles. The problem is that the modules I am using don't seem to work (or maybe I'm just not using them correctly, I am new to this aspect of druple. I have so far tried "Content Access", "Node access node reference", and "Node access user reference"). I was hoping to be able to restrict view access to a node completely by using some kind of reference field, so that it would also not show up in a view. Any Ideas on how to do either of these?